# Change the foreground of a button when clicked

Tags: xaml, button, colors, uwp

So all I am trying to do is change the color of a button when clicked but I've spent a good amount with errors and couldn't find anything helpful. Understand I am brand new to Visual Studio 2015 community.

There seems to be a lot of ways to do this either using brushes or solidcolorbrushes or a conversion.

Please mention using and references needed

here is my button:

```
<Button x:Name="CastButton"
        Click="CastButton_Click"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Margin="0,0,35,10"
        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
        FontSize="24"
        Foreground="AliceBlue"
        Content="&#xE72D;">
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the foreground color when the button is pressed, you will have to modify the *Style* of your control. Right click on your button in designer window, then <kbd>Edit Template</kbd>-><kbd>Edit a Copy</kbd> - this should create a copy of default template in resources, it should look like this:

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,4,8,4"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <!--Here is the change of foreground when pressed-->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

You will find out that button's colors are changed by visual state manager, depending on current state. In *Pressed* state you will find this:

```xml
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}"/>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

This means, that no matter you set to the *Foreground*, when pressed, visual state manager will always change button's color to *SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush*. Of course you are free to change this value in the style. Then only apply it to your button:

```xml
<Button Content="Button with style" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Okay I meant the color change would be toggled with each click on or off. I managed to find a cheap method to change the color using


        `private void CastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CastButton.Foreground = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(0xff, 0xff, 0x90, 0x90));
        }`

Comment: @John If you want an on/off button, then why not to use [ToggleButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.togglebutton)?

Comment: because I'm new and need to research more... :(

Comment: @John That's not a problem. Of course for *ToggleButton* you can also change its style (you can get it similar way like in the answer above via designer window), there you will surely find suitable states. If the style hasn't changed, it will look somehow like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx).