# Button's Background in Xaml UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

in a UWP application I have a button its Background property is set to "DeepPink", but whenever I hover my mouse over it, it changes to gray (the default color),

here is my code:

`<Button  Content="Hello World" Margin="100,0,0,0" Background="DeepPink"/>`

Am I missing something??

Comment: Just edit the *Style* of the control and modify appropriate *VisualStates* - [here is similar answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35263077/2681948) regarding changing behavior on clicked.

Comment: Yo, Do I have to write all that to make it work? I don't understand what it is?

Comment: You may either use designer to pull out the style (as it's mentioned in the answer) or you can copy the style from it (it should be the same). Then you will find *VisualState* which is responsible for *PointerOver* - this is the one you are interested in - play with it and comment out the things you don't need.

Comment: Thank you man, thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only defines the default state of the button, not the hover state.

You can either create a custom control template (you can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394219/358596)), or go the easy way of changing colors with [Lightweight styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles#lightweight-styling) - I'd recommend the second!

Comment: Hey, I have a question if I have like 20 buttons, do I need to do this 20 times?

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative would be to create Buttons like UI using Frame and Label. In this case, the background color will remain the same.

Example:

```
<Frame Padding="8" WidthRequest="100" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="Gray" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center">
       <Label Text="Button" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
</Frame>
```